# Summernote data-value returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<?php $i=-1; foreach($contents as $content): ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $content->contentName; ?>">
        <div class="summernote" data-value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <?php echo $content->content; ?>
        </div>
        <textarea name="<?php echo $content->contentName; ?>" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And then some javascript:

```
<script>
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    onblur: function(e) {
      var id = $(e.target).data('value');
      var sHTML = $(e.target).code();
      $("#"+id).val(sHTML);
    }
  });
</script>
```

My problem is that the `var id` returns as `undefined` What do I need to do to get this return the correct id.

Comment: If onblur is triggered by .summernote then you can just use $(this).data(...)

Comment: It returns as `undefined` as well.

Comment: try logging `e` and `e.target` just to be sure

Comment: I don't know what summernote is but you can log the e and the e.target to find out what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing summernote creates the app inside the div so try

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    onblur: function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).closest('[data-value]').data('value');
    }
});
```

OR assuming summernote does not get rid of the class

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    onblur: function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).closest('.summernote').data('value');
    }
});
```

Again I don't know summernote at all, if this does not work, it would help if you posted the generated html or a simplified version of it